# Web Site which displays announcements lists, other lists from Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What would be the way to Display the announcements lists, other lists from Sharepoint 2007 from a remote web site.

My Scenario : A user logs in on a (php) web page, which displays content from its own DB, but also has to display content from the announcements of a Sharepoint 2007. The web page is NOT on the same domain as the SharePoint server.

What should I use in my web page, and what should I configure on the sharepoint server ?

Additionally, how can I pass the user/password to the sharepoint and realize a single sign on ?

Hope this question is not to trival, but Im not familiar at all with sharepoint.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not trivial. You need to deal with the authentication issues first. It depends on what auth method SharePoint is using. You haven't said whether the page you are building will be within the same domain as SharePoint, but if it is and you're using Windows auth, then you should be OK.

In 2007, you can use the SOAP web services. Take a look at my SPServices jQuery library to make this easier, though you may need to roll your own calls in php.

Another option is to simply AJAX in a page from SharePoint that shows the announcements and then screen scrape the view from the DOM. That will give you the content, but the markup won't be what you probably want.

Comment: 10x for answering. The web page is not on the same domain as the SharePoint server. Do you have any idea, how this is done? Do I have to set up the SharePoint to use the web services ?

Comment: Btw how could the single sign-on can be realized in the same domain ?

Comment: Windows auth would just work. The SOAP Web Services are native and always on.